# Display numbers for 1 to 10 in 3 column

Tags: php

I am trying to display numbers for 1 to 10 in 3 column.

I need to be it:

1 5 8

2 6 9

3 7 10

4

This my code below, but it works wrong

```
$elems = 10;  

$array = array();
for ($q = 1; $q <= $elems; $q++)
    $array[] = $q;

$categories = $array;
$columns = 3;
$rows = 4;

echo '<table>';
for ($row = 0; $row < $rows; $row++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($categories as $k => $category) {
        if ($k % $rows == $row) {
            echo '<td>' . $category . '</td>';
        }
    }

    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

But I've got:

1 5 9

2 6 10

3 7

4 8

Comment: what result should be if there was an 11 elements (or 13)?

Comment: In the desired output, why does the first column have more elements than the 2nd?  What's the logic?

Comment: It calls "even output". All lines should be filled with minimum empty space.

Comment: for 11 elements It should be 1.2.3.10 new col 4.5.6.11 new col 7.8.9

Comment: what about 13 elements?

Comment: @СтаниславГидлевский, done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I would rewrite your algorithm to faster one:

```
$elems = 10;

$categories = range(1, $elems);
$columns = 3;
$rows = 4;

echo '<table>' . PHP_EOL;
for ($row = 0; $row < $rows; $row++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($col = 0; $col < $columns; $col++) {
        echo '<td>' . @$categories[$rows * $col + $row] . '</td>';
    }

    echo '</tr>' . PHP_EOL;
}

echo '</table>';
```

than, you need to count elements in each column, like this:

```
$elems_in_col = array();
$elem_left = $elems;
for ($col = 0; $col < $columns; $col++) {
    if ($elem_left % ($columns - $col) == 0) {
        $elems_in_col[$col] = $elem_left / ($columns - $col);
    } else {
        $elems_in_col[$col] = ceil($elem_left / ($columns - $col));
    }
    $elem_left -= $elems_in_col[$col];
}
var_export($elems_in_col);
```

this will gives us:

```
array (
  0 => 4,
  1 => 3,
  2 => 3,
)
```

and change a little bit our output logic. complete result would be:

```
$elems = 10;

$categories = range(1, $elems);
$columns = 3;
$rows = 4;

$elems_in_col = array();
$elem_left = $elems;
for ($col = 0; $col < $columns; $col++) {
    if ($elem_left % ($columns - $col) == 0) {
        $elems_in_col[$col] = $elem_left / ($columns - $col);
    } else {
        $elems_in_col[$col] = ceil($elem_left / ($columns - $col));
    }
    $elem_left -= $elems_in_col[$col];
}

echo '<table>' . PHP_EOL;
for ($row = 0; $row < $rows; $row++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($col = 0; $col < $columns; $col++) {
        if ($elems_in_col[$col] < $row + 1) {
            echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
            continue;
        }
        $idx = 0;
        for ($i = $col - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
            $idx += $elems_in_col[$i];
        }
        $idx += $row;
        echo '<td>' . @$categories[$idx] . '</td>';
    }

    echo '</tr>' . PHP_EOL;
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I will take my time to understand how it works.

Comment: you are welcome to ask in case you don't understand something =) possibly it wil work for any number of items/columns/rows, just make sure that `columns * rows > number of items`